# Only browser causes BSOD -- all other TCP operations okay

Tags: windows, browser, bsod, tcpip

A few weeks ago I started getting BSODs -- mostly in TCPIP.SYS, but occassionally Memory Parity.

I had some viruses which are now all removed.

I got new memory -- didn't fix it.

Over time I was able to narrow it down like this:

- IE 6, 7, 8 -- *all cause BSOD* after anywhere from a few minutes to an hour
- Google Chrome, Firefox  -- *all cause BSOD* after anywhere from a few minutes to an hour
- iTunes store -- *causes BSOD* after a few minutes (I believe the store is HTTP based)
- Remote Desktop -- *works fine*; ran it all night with no problems
- FTP -- *works fine*
- SQL -- *works fine*; ran a program all night that queried remote DB.  (Used Wireshark to verify it's using TCP as opposed to UDP.)

So -- is there some HTTP operation that is corrupted and causing TCPIP.SYS to BSOD?  Or is there something unique about HTTP that is putting some hardware load on the NIC and causing the BSOD.

This is bizarre!

Comment: And it sounds like it's time to reinstall the Operating System.

Answer (score 2):

> I had some viruses which are now all
>   removed.

ha, no way - unless you did a reinstall of your OS.

Answer (score 1):

> I had some viruses which are now all removed.

To expand on Mr-sk's answer, if you are still using the same install of Windows (no reformat/reinstall), then you almost certainly *haven't* completely cleaned your system.

Don't mistake your virus scanner returning "0 viruses found" as meaning that you are clean. It's a very good bet that you still have some nasty junk on your system. Viruses and other malware are often designed to avoid detection from scanners. You should think of malware like cockroaches - for every one that you see, assume there are others that you (and your antivirus software) *aren't* seeing.

It's a good rule of thumb to reformat and reinstall Windows anytime you've had more than just the most trivial of infestation, and/or if you're still experiencing anything other than perfect functionality after cleaning out an infestation. It sounds like you fall into both of those categories. Reinstall and start fresh.

Answer (score 0):

You should reinstall windows.

If you really don't want to do that, try repairing the TCP stack;
[Winsock fix](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Network-Tweak/WinSockFix.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Windows [System File Checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310747)?  It may repair it without having to reinstall. Have your Windows disk handy. :)

Answer (score 0):

If reinstalling Windows is a big chore at the moment (and when is it not?), you might be able to get away with resetting your TCP/IP system in Windows.  Go to [Microsoft's website here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357) and try their instructions on resetting it.  Of course, if you still have viruses in the system (as suggested above), then reinstalling Windows isn't a bad idea.  I would personally try the reset myself, and then test it out by going to several different antivirus websites and running the online scanners they have.  This will let you double, triple, maybe even quadruple check your system and you can be more certain that it is clean before spending hours wiping and re-installing Windows and your applications.