# Random BSOD, even when the computer idles

Tags: windows, bsod, tcpip, ntoskrnl.exe

I get a random BSOD, even when the computer idles.

Already tried:

- memtest - ok
- `scandisk` - ok
- `netsh int ip reset`
- Winsock fix.

> tcpip.sys+2c13e 21.06.2011 15:21:00   DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
>
> tcpip.sys+2de08   22.06.2011 15:09:28 DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
>
> tcpip.sys+2de08   22.06.2011 16:09:31 DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
>
> tcpip.sys+2c13e   23.06.2011 9:48:16  DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
>
> Fastfat.SYS+4dc   21.06.2011 11:55:10 SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
>
> ipnat.sys ipnat.sys+6751
>   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+699e0
>   tcpip.sys   tcpip.sys+2c13e 0
>
> HTTP.sys  HTTP.sys+15d00
>   ipnat.sys   ipnat.sys+6751
>   tcpip.sys   tcpip.sys+2de08
>
> ipnat.sys ipnat.sys+6751
>   ntoskrnl.exe    ntoskrnl.exe+79d94
>   tcpip.sys   tcpip.sys+2c13e
>
> Fastfat.SYS   Fastfat.SYS+4dc
>   ntkrnlpa.exe  ntkrnlpa.exe+8d820
>
> HTTP.sys HTTP.sys+15d00
>   ipnat.sys   ipnat.sys+6751
>   tcpip.sys   tcpip.sys+2de08

Here is [.dmp files and report](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=7e5eafae5336f402&resid=7E5EAFAE5336F402!116) generated by BlueScreenView.

I know this questions, but its answers did not help: [Only browser causes BSOD — all other TCP operations okay](https://superuser.com/questions/95088/only-browser-causes-bsod-all-other-tcp-operations-okay).

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it can be a few things:

1. Network driver hardware error.
2. Network card/chip problem/broken.
3. Windows TCP/IP stack has become corrupt.
4. Power management error.

The solutions are:

1. Try updating the driver.
2. Purchase a new card.
3. Try going to a command prompt (elevated) and type `SFC /SCANNOW`.
4. Try looking in the BIOS and possibly lower the supported power mode.

4b). In addition, possibly look and see if there are any chipset/system updates for your machine as it could be more related to power management features than the network card directly.

Hope this helps, but, BSODs are one thing that are very hard to help with remotely.